Variáveis de ambiente com Spring Boot
Alguém sabe como acessar variáveis de ambiente do .env no application.properties, mas não estou conseguindo, em outros trecho do codigo consigo normalmente, mas no applcation.properties eu não consigo, eu queria para armazenar informações do banco de dados

# application.properties
spring.application.name=demo
message=${hello}-mundo

// DemoApplication.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Value("${message}")
    private String properties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(properties);
    }
}

Configuração das variáveis de ambiente:

Output: world-mundo
Certifique-se de estar carregando as variáveis de ambiente antes do spring resolver os valores de ambiente. Se você fizer da forma que mostrei ele estará disponível para o spring.
